# Arduino interrupt frequency

Tags: c++, c, arduino, interrupt

I am using an Arduino uno to measure the speed of a dc motor.
I have a opto sensor that gives a pulse when the motor has made a full turn.
The problem I've got starts when the motor has a speed > 90Hz.
As soon as I reach 90Hz, the Arduino doesn't enter the interrupt function.

My code:

```
int pin = 13;
volatile int state = LOW;
volatile unsigned long startTijd = 0;
volatile unsigned long eindTijd = 0;
unsigned int frequentie = 0;
volatile int count = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0, blink, FALLING); //LOW, HIGH, FALLING, RISING, CHANGE

  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop()
{
  noInterrupts();
  digitalWrite(pin, state);
  interrupts();
}

void blink()
{
  if (count == 0) {
    startTijd = micros();
  }
  count++;
  if (count == 31) {
    count = 0;
    eindTijd = micros();
    eindTijd -= startTijd;
    Serial.print(eindTijd);
    Serial.print(" ms. - ");

    frequentie = 30 * 1000000 / eindTijd;
    Serial.print(frequentie);
    Serial.println(" Hz.");

  }
  state = !state;

}
```

My question is : When the Arduino receives interrupts at 90Hz, it doesn't execute the code in the interrupt. When the motor goes below 90Hz after that, the code works again. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: When the Arduino receives interrupts at 90Hz, it doesn't execute the code in the interrupt. When the motor goes below 90Hz after that, the code works again. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @NickRaeven Are you certain the opto sensor handles a frequency of > 90Hz ? or - how long does it assert the signal you're measuring ?

Comment: What's the real resolution of `micros()`?  Are you certain it's not being called, or do you just no longer see output on the serial port?  Can you toggle a GPIO port and set an oscope to trigger on a level change?

Comment: perhaps you should ask this on the Arduino site: http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BrianCainThe opto gives out +5v pulses for every Hz. This works (oscilloscope) even for higher frequencies (at least up to 200Hz).
I also trigger a LED on pin 13. This one stops changing status after 90+ Hz.

Comment: Can you clarify which version of Arduino this is? Is it the 8-bit Atmel version or the ARM version?

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though blink is your ISR.  If that's the case, you shouldn't be doing debug I/O within that routine for 2 reasons.  The first is that you are calling a process that could block.  The second is that ISRs should do their thing and finish (should be highly efficient).  My guess is that if you remove the debug I/O from your ISR and pass info back to the interrupted task instead (safely, of course) you will be able to service interrupts at greater than 90 hz.

Comment: Also if this is code is for a crappy 8-bit MCU, then 32 bit arithmetic alone is likely going to be too slow to be handled inside an ISR.

Comment: The arithmetic is far faster than serial IO, which is blocking in arduino libs. Get rid of it within the ISR.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to @Bruce answer. You are using serial IO in the interrupt. Each time you are printing around 15-20 characters (depending on the values calculated). Each character is encoded by `8` bit data + `1` start bit + `1` stop bit = `10` bits. So, say `20*10=200` bits. The baud rate is `19200`bps, so time required to transmit 200 bits is `200/19200` sec, or in terms of frequency `19200/200=96Hz`. So this is the **maximum** frequency achievable for transmission of 20 characters, which is close to your measured `90Hz` (take in account that I am not considering any time spacing overhead between the transmits).